# Get last insert id from last inserted row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, last-insert-id

I'm here again and I'm getting crazy!
I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `aggiungi_categoria`(IN   `id_categoria_principale` INT, IN `nome_categoria` VARCHAR(150), IN `sigla_categoria`    VARCHAR(10), IN `stato_categoria` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY   DEFINER
begin

select @rgt := rgt,@lft := lft from categorie where id = id_categoria_principale;

if @rgt - @lft = 1 then

UPDATE categorie SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @lft;
UPDATE categorie SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @lft;

insert into categorie (nome,sigla,stato,lft,rgt)
values(nome_categoria,sigla_categoria,stato_categoria,@lft+1,@lft+2);

 ELSE

 UPDATE categorie SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @rgt-1;
 UPDATE categorie SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @rgt-1;

 insert into categorie (nome,sigla,stato,lft,rgt) values
(nome_categoria,sigla_categoria,stato_categoria,@rgt,@rgt+1);

 end if;


 end
```

how can i get the last insert id??? i tried all, with out param or doing a select with max(id) on the table or "set last_id = last_insert_id()" but i don't know how to get it via php?

when i call the procedure in phpmyadmin i'm getting something like

```
@rgt:=number,@lft:=number2
```

and in php obviously i get the same result in array.

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` in PHP doesn't work? (or `$mysqli->insert_id` if you use MySQLi)

Comment: Is it a MySQL database? If so, what extension are you using, ie mysql, mysqli, pdo etc?

Comment: @MartinMajer i used it directly at the end of the procedure, like select last_insert_id() into last_id or set set last_id = last_insert_id(), where last_id is the out param.

Comment: @RossWilson yes it is, anyway i'm using mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it!

i added an int output parameter called last_id,
before the end tag i included this statement:

```
select last_insert_id() into last_id;
```

In PHP i execute:

```
$db -> execQuery('call aggiungi_categoria('.$parametri['id_categoria_principale'].',"'.$parametri['nome'].'","'.$parametri['sigla'].'",'.$parametri['stato'].',@lastId);');
```

and finally

```
$lid = $db ->execQuery('select @lastId;');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `mysql_insert_id‎` to fetch the id for the last insert statement.
Reference: http://php.net/mysql_insert_id‎

However, `mysql_*` functions are, now, deprecated (read below) and you should use an equivalent `mysqli_*` function or method. The equivalent for the above function would be: `$mysqli->insert_id()`
Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

The `mysql_*` category of functions have been deprecated, and the warning is reproduced here:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension
>   should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and
>   [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function
>   include:
>
> - [mysqli_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)
> - [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: yes i'm sorry i miss to tell you i'm using mysqli, i have function in my db class that return $mysqli->insert_id() but it doesn't work , result 0. Instead when i do an insert query (without calling procedure) it works

Comment: @MarcoC If you look at my answer below, I believe it will help you out.

Comment: @RossWilson thank you , but in my case it doesn't work because i'm using "insert" inside the procedure. So i tried both and (in this case) my answer is the correct one. However your answer is correct but just when you execute the insert command as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQLi then your would have something like this.

Procedural:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_table);

$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES($val, $val2, $val3)";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

OOP:

```
$mysqli = new mysql($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_table);

//query
$id = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Hope this helps!

Let me know if you have any issues.